# how to declare type of list comprehension in python

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

What is the correct way to declare the type of the following function in Python?

```py
from typing import TypeVar, List

T = TypeVar('T')      # Declare type variable

def dual_combinator(self, a: List[T], b: List[T]) -> List[T]:
    return [x for x in a if x in b]
```

I'd like the type to indicate that the input variables `a` and `b` can be anything which is compatible with a list comprehension, and the `in` operator, respectively, and the output should be the output of a list comprehension.  I believe that `a: List[T]` and `b: List[T]` are probably too specific, and the return type `List[T]` is probably wrong as well.

I'm very new to this particular type system.  I haven't yet figured out how to find out information like this. It's probably described somewhere in the documentation, so I'd also appreciate a brief description of how to find such documentation in the future.

Comment: I think you want: `Iterable[T]`

Comment: Which one should be `Iterable[T]`, a, b, or the return type, or all of the above?

Comment: The inputs. A list comprehension always returns a list.

Comment: Sorry. Read the question wrongly. @Barmar methods looks right.

Comment: I can recommend Adam Johnson's blog (https://adamj.eu/tech/tag/mypy/) and the mypy docs (https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) as good python-typing resources

Answer (score 3):

The parameter you're iterating over should be `Iterable`, and the parameter you're searching should be `Container`.

```
from collections.abc import Iterable, Container

def dual_combinator(self, a: Iterable[T], b: Container[T]) -> List[T]:
    return [x for x in a if x in b]
```

The list comprehension always returns a list, so `List[T]` is the correct return type.

Comment: Thanks, Barmar, that's useful.  But the second part of my question was:  How was I supposed to figure this out for myself?   Knowing how to figure things like this out would be helpful for me in the future.

Comment: I found it by googling "python type hint iterable"

Comment: And that pointed me to https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: But you need to know that "iterable" is the general term for anything you can iterate over.

Comment: ahh so you already knew about `Iterable`.   By the way, I don't understand why `b` should be `Iterable`.   The list comprehension iterates over `a`, but not over `b`.

Comment: `x in b` iterates over `b` to search for `x`.

Comment: It iterates conceptually -- many types provide optimizations so it doesn't actually have to iterate.

Comment: hmm.  I didn't realize that `in` only works on iterables.  My gut feel was that there was probably a `__in__` method, and the `in` operator would be compatible with any type which has a `__in__` method.

Comment: I was simplifying. It actually uses the `__contains__` method, so any type that implements this would work.

Comment: voila, so `b` should not be `Iterable`; that would be too restrictive in general.   So is that something the type system is able to represent?

Comment: Yeah. I'm not sure there's a "searchable" type.

Comment: `collections.abc.Container` is good for hinting objects that need a `__contains__` method